The Continuity of the Galois Representation Attached to a Weight 2 Newform
A representation $\rho: G_{\mathbb Q} \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space for some field $K$, must be continuous in order to be considered a Galois representation. I have seen proofs of the continuity of the $\ell$-adic cyclotomic character and of the $\ell$-adic representation associated to an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$, but never for the $\ell$-adic representations associated to weight 2 cusp forms.
Let $\ell$ be a prime and let $f$ be a weight 2 newform. Fix a prime $\lambda$ above $\ell$ in the number field of $f$ (which is $\mathbb Q$ adjoin the Fourier coefficients of $f$). Why is Galois representation $\rho_{f, \lambda}$ attached to $f$ continuous?
I am looking for a fairly detailed answer, as I have already spent a good deal of time attempting to parse the details.

Assume for the sake of simplicity that your modular form $f$ is a newform for $\mathcal{S}_2(\Gamma_0(N))$.
Let $F/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field containing the Fourier coefficients of all newforms of weight $2$ and conductor dividing $N$. Fix a maximal ideal $\lambda$ of $\mathcal{O}_F$ with residue characteristic $\ell$.
Let $T$ be the $\ell$-adic Tate module of $J_0(N)$.
Step 1: the $\ell$-adic Tate module of $J_0(N)$ is a (continuous) Galois representation.
Proof: by definition of the profinite topology, it is equivalent to show that, for all $n \geq 1$, $G_{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(J_0(N)[\ell^n])$ is continuous.
In other words, it is equivalent to show that, for any $n \geq 1$, $G_{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(J_0(N)[\ell^n])$ has an open kernel (the target is a finite group), ie that $\mathbb{Q}(J_0(N)[\ell^n])$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. This can be shown point by point (every such point is defined over a finite subextension contained in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$) and $J_0(N)[\ell^n](\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ is finite.
Step 2: for any $F_{\lambda}$-basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $T \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}} F_{\lambda}$, the matrix coefficients of the Galois action in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ are continuous functions $G_{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow F_{\lambda}$.
Proof: Using elementary linear algebra, it is enough to show this for one particular basis $\mathcal{B}_0$. For $\mathcal{B}_0$, we choose a $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$-basis of $T$, so the result follows from step 1.
Step 3: Getting to the $f$-eigenspace.
Not a proof, since there’s not a claim: Let $V_{f,\lambda}$ be the subspace of $T \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}} F_{\lambda}$ on which $T_{q}(x)=a_q(f)x$ for any prime $q\nmid N$. Then $V_{f,\lambda}$ is a $2$-dimensional $F_{\lambda}$-subspace of $T \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}} F_{\lambda}$ stable under $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$.
Fix a $F_{\lambda}$-basis $\mathcal{B}=(e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_r)$ of $T \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}} F_{\lambda}$ where $(e_1,e_2)$ is a basis of $V_{f,\lambda}$.
Let $M_{\lambda}$ be the matrix of the Galois action in the basis $\mathcal{B}$. Because $V$ is stable under $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$, the $(i,j)$ coefficient of $M_{\lambda}$ vanishes identically when $i>2 \leq j$.
So the top-left $2\times 2$ submatrix $M_{f,\lambda}$ of $M_{\lambda}$ is a continuous map $G_{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_2(F_{\lambda})$. Moreover, it has nonzero determinant and is a group homomorphism to $GL_2(F_{\lambda})$.
Step 4: show that $M_{f,\lambda}$ is a realization of $\rho_{f,\lambda}$.
Proof sketch: the Eichler-Shimura relation tells you (by definition of the space $V_{f,\lambda}$ above) that any $M_{f,\lambda}(Frob_{q})$ annihilates $X^2-a_q(f)X+q$.
Showing that this is actually the characteristic polynomial (which is what is required, right?) is slightly trickier – this is done in Brian Conrad’s appendix to the Lectures on Serre’s Conjectures. I do not recall his argument very precisely, but it has to do with the Atkin-Lehner involution $w_N$.

Thank you, as usual! The only thing I don't follow is how the actual step 3 follows from the argument presented. Are we somehow invoking step 2?

Yes, it’s not too clearly formulated. I edited, I hope that it is better now.
